# How to get "Author" field for Wikimedia Commons audio file

Tags: wikipedia, wikimedia-commons

I'm going to ask this by example. Take a look at this media file's page

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sheerness.ogg

It has a table showing "Author" with a value of "Speaker: The Voice of Hassocks
Authors of the article". (I'm only interested in the "The Voice of Hassocks" part but the whole thing would be fine).

Is that author value accessible via the API? Generally speaking I can see how I can get other file info via, e.g.

[https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Sheerness.ogg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=timestamp|url|user|metadata|extmetadata&format=json](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Sheerness.ogg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=timestamp%7Curl%7Cuser%7Cmetadata%7Cextmetadata&format=json)

But looking through the output of that API request, I don't see "The Voice of Hassocks" appearing anywhere. Nor, looking through the API docs, do I see anything else other than metadata and extmetadata that might contain it. Is that "Author" info exposed via the API anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely in the output of your query.

In the Json output, look in `query> pages> 3532106> ImageInfo> 0> extmetadata> Artist> value`, and you'll get the following data, that may need some further data cleaning depending on your use case:

```
> '<p><b>Speaker:</b> <a
> href="//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:The_Voice_of_Hassocks"
> class="mw-redirect" title="User:The Voice of Hassocks">The Voice of
> Hassocks</a><br></p>\n<b><span class="plainlinks"><a rel="nofollow"
> class="external text"
> href="https://xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo/en.wikipedia.org/%5B%5Bw%3Aen%3ASheerness%7CSheerness%5D%5D/2008-02-10">Authors
> of the article</a></span></b>'
```

Depending on what you're after exactly, it may be worth looking into the sibling node `Credit> value` too.